# Why does Git hash only the Contents of A File?

Tags: git, hash

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225313/how-does-git-compute-file-hashes), the hash of a file in Git is computed

```
    Commit Hash (SHA1) = SHA1("blob " + <size_of_file> + "\0" + <contents_of_file>)
```

I tested it myself for two empty files to check whether it was correct:

```
    100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0       empty1.txt
    100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0       empty2.txt
```

But why does Git exclude the name of the file from the hash? How does it distinguish between empty1.txt and empty2.txt?

If I were to change the name of empty1.txt to empty2.txt, how does Git keep track of that change when I call git status?

Comment: Git manages a working directory via a tree structure.  In that tree structure, file names are mapped to SHA-1 blobs, in a dictionary fashion.  So the tree maintains the relationship between file name and SHA-1, not the blob itself.

Comment: Is this tree structure an explicit object (e.g. a HashMap)? And is this tree structure the same one from the structs of Git -- commits, trees, blobs, tags?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "explicit" object, but yes it stored somewhere.  Yes it is one of the four objects Git uses.

Comment: Ah that makes sense -- so when status is called, Git just makes comparisons between the tree of a commit and the tree of its parent, right?

Comment: I'm not certain of that...my knowledge of Git implementation is fairly limited.  I just wanted to point out that the blob SHA-1 is not the only thing which is used to identify a file, these blobs are part of a tree structure.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I'm just trying to understand how the staging works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765366/how-does-git-track-file-changes-internally

Comment: Maybe you should start with [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why does Git exclude the name of the file from the hash? How does it distinguish between empty1.txt and empty2.txt?

Because Git manages *content* (and if the content of two files is identical, their SHA1 would be too).

The file *names* are managed by the [*tree* (directory *content*)](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#_tree_objects), which lists the files in a given folder.

[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/data-model-2.png]

```
$ git cat-file -p 3c4e9cd789d88d8d89c1073707c3585e41b0e614
040000 tree d8329fc1cc938780ffdd9f94e0d364e0ea74f579      bak
100644 blob fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92      new.txt
100644 blob 1f7a7a472abf3dd9643fd615f6da379c4acb3e3a      test.txt
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, Git creates a tree with objects that are listed within the index. Is the type of an object (tree, blob) stored as well within that file along with its SHA-1? And then, how does Git use this index / tree to detect which files have been modified, untracked, or deleted?

Comment: Is index a tree itself that hasn't been associated with a commit? When I open the index of my repository, I'm noticing it has been serialized.

Comment: @SlackOverflow The type is part of the SHA1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21361195/6309

Comment: Edit: http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/10/git-tip-of-week-understanding-index.html seems to suggest that is not the case. Still, I wonder how index makes fast comparisons without being an object.

Comment: @SlackOverflow git status has improved recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667992/6309

Comment: Ah that was what I was thinking: index compares the modification time of each file, and if it differs, only then will it compute the SHA-1 hash of a file -- solely guessing off the fact that index keeps track of time metadata.